# How to set width independently for jQuery UI selectmenu button and selectmenu items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

My selectmenu button must have fixed size - no problem here.

Plus, when I click this button and pop-up items appear - I want each option to be shown in one line, without wrapping and without showing horizontal scrollbar.

I've tried different approaches, for instance:

```
$select.selectmenu({
  icons: { button: 'downArrowGreen' }
});
$select.selectmenu('widget').css('width', instance.getRealWidth($select) - 8);
$select.selectmenu('menuWidget').css('width', '[something, to fit the most wide $select element').addClass('overflow');
```

There are two problems appearing here:

1) for some reason, the size, set for 'menuWidget' (i.e. for pop-up part of menu), is ignored (seems it's set the same as for 'widget');

2) overflow class just adds some decoration, however it cannot know what this width should be - so the width should be calculated. But $select is hidden and no calculation is possible for its option items either...

UPDATE: I can see I can do this with _resizeMenu, but for me, it looks more like a hack. Also the question with calculating $select items width is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the ui-selectmenu-open class, e.g.
.ui-selectmenu-open {width: 20%;}

The strange thing is that its parent is the body element.